# Adding DataRow[] data to each column in an unbound DataGridView?

Tags: c#, database, arrays, datagridview, datarow

I am trying to query my DataSet and display the results in an unbound DataGridView. I feel like I am quite close with my programming logic here, but I keep getting the error `ArgumentOutOfRange Exception. Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.`

My code snippet:

```
DataRow[] foundRows;

//Queries the Reservations table with the 'searchExpression' variable
foundRows = this.reservationMasterDataSet.Tables["Reservations"].Select(searchExpression);

//If there is at least one record found...
if (foundRows.Length > 0)
{
    //Used to count our row indexes
    int i = 0;

    //Populate the DataGridView with the queried response
    foreach (DataRow row in foundRows)
        {
            //Used to count our column indexes
            for (int j = 0; j < reservationMasterDataSet.Tables["Reservations"].Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                //THIS LINE IS THROWING AN EXCEPTION
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value = row.ItemArray[j];        
            }

            i++;
        }
}
```

My `DataRow` contains 12 objects so I made sure that the `DataGridView` has 12 columns to correspond (and there are 12 in the original database). I think I am getting the exception right away (`i` is still `0` in debugger). I first tried it using just `row[i]` but got the same error.

This is meant to be a search results pane, not an editable thing, which is why I want to only return certain results. I figured the `DataGridView` is the nicest and easiest way to layout the record on a Windows form.

Comment: Does the DataGridView contains rows when you start this routine?

Comment: Oh. Actually, no I don't think it does. From the form designer view there aren't any rows, and I don't have any code that explicitly adds any. I guess I thought that's what this was doing, but you just set off the lightbulb over my head. :) I probably need to add new rows equal to the length of the foundRows array, right?

Comment: I love  this community. Chris, I just added `dataGridView1.Rows.Add();` to the beginning of the foreach loop and it's working. Please make this an answer so I can mark it and give you the props you deserve ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you access to `DataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j]`, you need to make sure  `DataGridView1.Rows[i]` exists. If no, you need to add it to the `DataGridViewRowCollection`.

You can find a lot of sample on on [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rows.aspx).

Comment: So simple, yet so hard to spot without someone helping. Thanks so much for taking the time to answer my question!

Comment: I was writing the answer when I receive your comment. Happy that you solved your issue. Also take a look at the link in the answer, there are samples that can simplify the rows creation by using arrays.